# Is there an easy way to print out a polynomial in Arkworks-rs Polynomial class?

Tags: rust, polynomials

I am using Arkworks-rs algebra library. Is there a simple way to print out a polynomial which has already been constructed. It's for debugging purposes.

I am not particularly worried about the format - as long as it is human readable.

For e.g. if the polynomials is "x^3 + 2x + 1" - then even printing out a vector like [1,2,0,1] (which are the coefficients) is good enough. I am actually interested in a multivariate polynomial (MVPolynomial), so it may be a more complicated format - but it's enough if it's human understandable. I couldn't find anything in the docs.

I am a experienced programmer though a total beginner with Rust.

Comment: Please put a link to the docs of the struct you want to print.

Comment: In particular, it is likely that it implements `Debug`.